# No IDP metadata From IDP

Tags: spring-saml, opensaml

In my project, IDP team did not provide any metadata file. How should I configure IDP metadata in my SP, which is based on Spring-SAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring SAML requires IDP metadata to operate. But you can of course simply create the metadata document by hand. It's an easy task to do - see some example (like the one in SSO Circle) and update it with your own certificate and endpoints.